# Divide List in Equal Parts

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, list

I have a big List that may have some `50,000` or more items and i have to do operation against each item.takes some `X` time now if i use conventional method and do operation in sequential  manner it is definitely take `X * 50,000` on average.

I planned to optimize and save some time and decided to use `Background Worker` as there is no dependency among them.Plan was to divide the List in 4 parts and use each in separate `Background Worker`.

I want to ASk

1.is this method DUMB?

2.Is there any other Better Method?

3.Suggest a nice and clean method to divide List in 4 equal Parts?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can use .Net 4.0, then use the Task Parallel library and have a look at

```
Parallel.ForEach()
```

[Parallel ForEach How-to.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd460720.aspx)

Everything is basically the same as a traditional for loop, but you work with parallelism implicitly.

Comment: 4.0 Client version Supports it?

Comment: Yes! `.NET Framework Client Profile` support it. Now mark it as answer! :D

Comment: Ok bro i will definitely mark it need to wait 6 min to do that

Comment: I wrote code and parallel foreach also hangs for a while when there is 5 items in list so if there is big list then?????

And secondly instead of dividing list to 4 parts should i only use one parallel foreach or parallel foreach is replacement of backgroundworker

Comment: @Afnan You still want to use a backgroundworker to get the loop off of the main thread so it does not block your program. However you do not need to spawn more than one as (this is a really simplified model) internally Parallel.ForEach is spawning background workers internally for you.

Comment: If i am not wrong it is faster than regular foreach in background worker? and it depends on length of the list to do parallel processing?

Answer (score 2):

You can also really split it to groups.

I didn't see a built-in sequence method for it, so here's the low level way. point out any blunders please. I am learning.

```
static List<T[]> groups<T>(IList<T> original, uint n)
    {
        Debug.Assert(n > 0);
        var listlist = new List<T[]>();
        var list = new List<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < original.Count(); i++)
        {
            var item = original[i];
            list.Add(item);
            if ((i+1) % n == 0 || i == original.Count() - 1)
            {
                listlist.Add(list.ToArray());
                list.Clear();
            }

        }
     return listlist;
    }
```

Comment: parallel.foreach serves the purpose

Answer (score 1):

Another version, based on linq.

```
public static List<T[]> groups<T>(IList<T> original, uint n)
{
        var almost_grouped = original.Select((row, i) => new { Item = row, GroupIndex = i / n });
        var groups = almost_grouped.GroupBy(a => a.GroupIndex, a => a.Item);
        var grouped = groups.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToList();
        return grouped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good method for optimizing similar, independent, operations on a large collection. However, you should look at the Parallel.For method in .NET 4.0. It does all the heavy lifting for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx